# Can a verb "secure" be used in this context?

Tags: word-usage

Can "Secure your iphones" be used in the context that iphone stocks are running low at a market and one ought to purchase it as quickly as possible?

In Christmas, can a dad say a sentence like "I need to go to Walmart to secure iron man toy before it gets sold out"?

Comment: Yes, you can use 'secure your iPhones' in the context you explain.

Answer (score -3):

"Secure your iPhone" is not idiomatic English usage. The words could be interpreted to mean "keep it safely" or even "protect it from viruses".

Common expressions used to encourage people to buy, are:

"Buy now while stocks last!" 
"Hurry while stocks last!" and
"Get yours before stocks run out!"

They mean purchase quickly while supplies are still available.

Alternatively, if you wanted to place an order, you might say:

"Reserve your iPhone while stocks last!*

http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/buy-now-while-stocks-last.1259413/
http://www.tolearnenglish.com/forum/lire.php?num=6&msg=62362&titre=While+stock+last